# How to order data.table by custom column

Tags: r, data.table

Ordering of the data.frame by column index:

```
> df <- data.frame(5:9, 8:4)
> df
  X5.9 X8.4
1    5    8
2    6    7
3    7    6
4    8    5
5    9    4
> df[order(df[,2]),]
  X5.9 X8.4
5    9    4
4    8    5
3    7    6
2    6    7
1    5    8
```

or by column name:

```
> df[order(df[,"X5.9"]),]
  X5.9 X8.4
1    5    8
2    6    7
3    7    6
4    8    5
5    9    4
```

Is it possible to achieve the same with data.table and order by custom column name or index?

Comment: Have a look at `setorder`:  `library("data.table")
setDT(df)
setorder(df, X5.9)`

Comment: Or just: `setDT(df, key = 'X5.9')`

Comment: I'm guessing no one's showing you the way to do it by column number because it's discouraged/considered a bad idea. See FAQ 1.1 https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#j-num

Comment: If you have the column name stored as a string, `col = "X5.9"`, the idiom would be `df[ order(get(col)) ]` , I guess.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `setkey`

```
setkey(setDT(df), X5.9)
```